# Reproducing electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, acoustics

We all know reproducing solar energy is possible.
Same stands for mechanical energy (air, water, coals) - they are all reproducible.

But what about other types of light ?
A diode light for example that differs from the solar light tremendously.
So can we convert its type of light back into electricity?

---

Videlicet,
can we convert another types of energy into electricity, after the consumer has been supplied ? 
For instance converting noises back to EAS and then from EAS to electricity ?

Comment: Can you define "reproducible"? Do you mean "renewable"? I thought so until you mentioned coal, which is definitely not included in the "renewable" group of energy sources. Also, what is "EAS"?

Comment: @Brionius I think "Renewable" also makes sense to me. I mean I am just not a native speaker, especially not familiar with academic words related to science. "EAS" is "Electrical Audio Signal". It is converted to a sound.

Comment: I rather used the coal as a general part taker of the energy conversion process.

Comment: While accepting that you are not a native speaker, and may have difficulty formulating your question, I would like you to try to expand on your question to make clear what you are asking. Are you asking about converting one type of energy to another? Whether there are different "kinds" of photons? It is really not clear. Please use the "edit" function to improve your question so we may try to answer it.

Comment: @Floris done. I tried.

Comment: @Malina - much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is "yes". For most energy conversion processes, the "inverse" process exists. Typically though, as you go from one to the other, and back again, you will lose some efficiency - think of it as the universe entropy increasing at every step of the way.

Specifically, with regard to your two examples:

The light from an LED consists of photons - once they leave the LED there is no way of knowing whence they came. And so if you hit a photodiode with LED light, you will induce a current. If you illuminated the same diode with photons from the sun, filtered by wavelength, you would get the same current per photon. Specific photo cells (like CdTe "solar panels") may or may not be sensitive for the wavelength of the LED in question - but that is not a matter of the *source* of the light itself, just the *frequency*. Which could be generated by the sun or any other light source.

And just like a loudspeaker can convert electricity into sound, you can in fact use a loudspeaker as a microphone. This type of microphone is sometimes called "dynamic" to distinguish it from a condenser style microphone. The ear phones commonly used with iPods etc are good (enough) microphones - I am aware of at least one medical instrument that was developed in Israel that used one ear bud of headphones as a source of sound, and the other as the receiver (microphone). By moving a coil in a magnetic field, you induce a current - just as driving a current through the coil will cause it to move.

The efficiency is often quite poor - but the process is possible.

Comment: I am asking because my area of expertise is programming and electric engineering. In my vast feature I would like to build something major and the prototype must be fully resistible of variety of different fettles and its supply must be independent and eternal (well maybe not eternal but long-lasting). So this is why I am asking. It wasn't just curiosity. (I suspected it will have loose of efficiency)

Comment: Thanks too. Also regarding the loose of efficiency, electromagnetic stabilizer should help in some circumstances (depending on the energy to be converted of course)

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for "energy harvesting" technology to keep some device running forever. When you google that term you will find devices and reference designs optimized to convert power (DC-DC converters, etc). May be helpful.

Comment: When my microphone broke a few years ago, I just plugged my earbuds into my microphone port and used those effectively until I got a new one. So I'll vouch that speakers can be used as a microphone